# How to check if an input matches a set of desired values without repeating myself?

Tags: python, boolean

I want to be able to do something like this, where inputs of 1, "D" or "dog" will all call `do_something()`, whereas any other input will call `do_something_else()`.

```
command = input("Type a command")
if command == (1 or "D" or "dog"):
   do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Currently, this does not work, because Python is evaluating the truthiness of `(1 or "D" or "dog")`, which is always `True`, of course. Then, since `command` is also a true string, `do_something` will always be called.

**I know how to do this one way:** `if command == 1 or command = "D" or command = "dog"`. This works fine; however, it involves a lot of repetition, and I'm sure there must be some way to shorten that.

I suppose I could also make a list of valid commands, `valid_commands = [1,"D","dog"]` and check `if command in valid_commands`, but that seems like a workaround, rather than the ideal approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `in` operator:

```
command = input("Type a command")
if command in ["1","D","dog"]:
   do_something()
else:
   do_something_else()
```